# How to Trim leading and trailing tab spaces in MSSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have data which has leading and trailing spaces in the string. when storing that data in database I want to trim the space in query itself before storing into DB.

Normal spaces are trimming properly with RTRIM and LTRIM function but if a string contains tab space,its not trimming the tab space from the input string.

Can anyone help me to get the string with trimmed with tab space from leading and trailing.

Comment: replace all tabs with spaces, trim the intermediate string, then convert spaces back to tabs?

Answer (score 21):

Replace the ASCII code for tab (9):

```
replace(@str, char(9), '')
```

To only remove the outer tabs, first change them to something that won't exist in your data (I use a series of four spaces in this example), then rtrim/ltrim, then convert that same sequence back to tabs:

```
replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(@str, char(9), '    '))),'    ', char(9));
```

Comment: this will replace all tab space in between the string as well, I want only the leading and trailing space.

Comment: @user3876801 I updated the answer to include this scenario.

Comment: what about the performance if data is very big as multiple time replace function is being used to convert the data.

Comment: @user3876801 That's probably something you'll have to test to determine, as I don't have any knowledge of your infrastructure.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @InputString nvarchar(50) = CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + ' 123'+ 'abc ' + CHAR(9);
SELECT @InputString AS InputString
      ,REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(RIGHT(@InputString, LEN(@InputString) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+']%', @InputString) + 1)), LEN(REVERSE(RIGHT(@InputString, LEN(@InputString) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+']%', @InputString) + 1))) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+']%', REVERSE(RIGHT(@InputString, LEN(@InputString) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+']%', @InputString) + 1))) + 1)) AS OutputString
;
```

Maybe you should refactor it as a function. Note, it may works only above Sql Server 2008. You can replace CHAR(9) to any character you like to trim.